# View kernel printk debug messages

Tags: linux, kernel

When using `pr_debug("blah\n")` messages do not appear in output of `dmesg`. I have `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` set to 8 4 1 7. `pr_alert` messages show up just fine. Any ideas please?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/local/pr_debug.txt

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `DEBUG` **macro** for make `pr_debug` to actually print.

E.g., if add the line

```
ccflags-y := -DDEBUG=1
```

into the module's `Makefile`, then `pr_debug` called by any source file of that module will actually print information.

---

Alternatively, if `DEBUG` macro is not defined but the kernel is built with **option** `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` enabled, you may dynamically control which `pr_debug` call should actually print.

E.g. after executing (from root)

```
echo 'module my_module' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

all `pr_debug` called from the module `my_module` will actually print information.

For more information about dynamic debugging see [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html).

Comment: This answer is wrong. The statement is correct for pr_devel, for pr_debug CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG may also be specified. See also https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-basics.html

Comment: @spawn: I have updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

If inserting a module use option e.g `insmod hello.ko dyndbg=+p`. See `Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt` in the kernel tree.

You also may need `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y`